# Django Rest: How to implement registration, 3rd part and local oauth authentication?

Tags: django, rest, authentication, oauth, registration

Like many, I'm in the process of creating a mobile application backed by a Django application and communicating via REST API. While the choice of the Django Rest Framework was easy, the choice of the additional component is tricky for me. I'm just discovering this ecosystem so it could be that I'm just looking at it the wrong way. These are my requirements:

The users should be able to create and edit an account (userena profile)  via the mobile application, without necessarily using a third party (Facebook for example but it is planed for future feature). The registration process should include email verification.
The authentication process should be following OAuth, so the authentication module should provide a way to implement an OAuth provider.

I looked at [this page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages) but couldn't find any modules which provided all of these out of the box. Particularly I checked:

- Djoser: Seems to provide registration (including email validation), token authentication but no OAuth.
- django-rest-auth : Registration (including email verification), token authentication, 3rd part OAuth authentication but no custom OAuth provider implementation (?)
- django-rest-framework-social-oauth2: OAuth provider, 3rd part OAuth authentication but no registration.

Did I misunderstand these modules or am I looking at it the wrong way? Otherwise, can the modules be mixed? Which would you advise?
Is there an easy way to take one module and, from there, add a custom implementation of the last functionality? (I saw post about implementing user registration manually but didn't find the email validation part...)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I use django-rest-auth in my projects, adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_application.custom_user_model'` will enable you use custom user model. In your custom user model you can modify user creation and also do lots of actions using django `signals` like custom things after or before user creation. That should solve your problem. Also it will be better to check `allauth` which also have support for Google, Facebook and other login providers.

Comment: Thank you for the indications. I need to look into what you mention because so far it doesn't talk to me. Is the point of what you're suggesting to implement the user registration myself? Isn't it already included in django-rest-auth?

Comment: Django uses its own user module, but you can build new User model using its `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` class and  it will have same features as django's user system + your custom modifications like extra fields for user. Most of plugins like django-rest-auth will work with your custom user module without any problem. Also you can use django's user model without changing it in signal. `post_save` and `pre_save` will give you needed power to make custom  tasks before and after user creation, modification and etc.

Comment: Actually, I reviewed these and I'm a bit in the dark there. While I see the potential that you are trying to show me, I don't see how to use it to my advantage. As indicated, the issue that I had identified with django-rest-auth is not about the registration process but about the absence of facility to create my own OAuth provider. Using the customization possibilities to create this appears pretty complicated to me. More than trying to create a registration process with another module. Did I misunderstand you? What do you suggest I put in the `post_save` and `pre_save` ?